# How should I prove that this inequality is always true?

Tags: inequalities

When $e<a<b<e^{2}$, $ \ln ^{2} b-\ln ^{2} a>\frac{4}{e^{2}}(b-a)$ should always hold.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, E < a < b < E^2, 
  Log[b]^2 - Log[a]^2 > 4/E^2 (b - a)], Reals]
```

However, the above code is returned as it is. How can I modify it to get true or prove that the inequality always is true?

Comment: Ask it at MSE. This is rather math than Mathematica.

Comment: @user64494 I already know the mathematical proof process, but I want to use MMA's built-in functions to solve this problem.

Comment: The function `f[x_]:=Log[x]^2 - 4/Exp[2]*x` is strictly increasing on the interval `Interval[{E, E^2}]`. Hope the rest is clear, however, don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 No need to get snippy here. This is a perfectly reasonable question about how to use Mathematica's capabilities for problems like this.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Here is the realization of my proposal. The command `Minimize[{D[Log[x]^2 - 4/Exp[2]*x, x], x > E && x < E^2}, x]` produces the warning "Minimize::wksol: Warning: there is no minimum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; returning a result on the boundary." and `{0, {x -> E^2}}`. This implies an affirmative answer to the question. Also `Resolve[ForAll[x, x > E && x < E^2, 
  D[Log[x]^2 - 4/Exp[2]*x, x] > 0], Reals]` produces `True` and an affirmative answer to the question.

Comment: However, both the above proposals need the Lagrange's Theorem to finish the proof, but   the Lagrange's Theorem is not implemented in Mathematica. In view of it I don't give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not a proof, but a numerical verification

`RegionPlot` shows that the conditions holds.

```
RegionPlot[ 
E < a < b < E^2 && Log[b]^2 - Log[a]^2 > 4/E^2 (b - a)
, {a, 0,10}, {b, 0, 10}, FrameLabel -> {a, b},GridLines -> {{E, E^2}, {E, E^2}},MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: This is not even a numeric verification.

Comment: If your comment would include a suggestion to do it better it could be helpful.

Comment: See my second comment to the question to this end.

Comment: Your comment gives an idea for the mathematical proof, not a numerical verification!

Comment: I wonder the .upvoters.It is a bad practice to approve a wrong  answer

Answer (score 1):

Not a mathematical proof, but you can use `NMinimize` to find the point that's most in danger of violating the inequality or see if there are obvious counter-examples:

```
objective = Log[b]^2 - Log[a]^2 - 4/E^2 (b - a);
cons = E < a < b < E^2
sol = NMinimize[{objective, cons}, {a, b}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> {6.4205140396121489208*10^-12, {a -> 2.7182895476079523458, b -> 2.7182895476409766661}}

As you can see, it's a pretty close call. Normally I'd use `Reduce`, but it seems like it gets stuck:

```
Reduce[E < a < b < E^2 && Log[b]^2 - Log[a]^2 > 4/E^2 (b - a)]
```

Comment: What is the absolute error of `NMinimize` by default? The absolute error of the analogous command of Maple `DirectSearch:-Search` equals $10^{-6}$.

Comment: @user64494 It depends on your working precision and accuracy/precision goal specifications. I suggest looking it up in the documentation. However, since `a == b == E` makes the objective 0, I suspect the objective goes to zero for better and better precision.

Comment: SioerdSmit (@ does not work.): Sorry, you avoid  answering my question.

Comment: @user64494 The default accuracy and precision goals for NMinimize depend on the working precision. "`AccuracyGoa -> Automatic` normally yields an accuracy goal equal to half the setting for WorkingPrecision." http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html

Comment: Sioerd Smit: Thank you. BTW, for each $a\in [e,e^2]$ and for each $\epsilon >0, \,\epsilon<1$  there exists $b\in [e,e^2], b>a,$ s.t. $\left|-\frac{4 (b-a)}{e^2}-\log ^2(a)+\log ^2(b)\right|< \epsilon$ so you result is meaningless.

Comment: @SioerdSmit: How about  the use of `NMinimize`  to `objective = Log[b]^2 - Log[a]^2 - 4/E^2 (b - a) - 10^-20000;
cons = E < a < b < E^2;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113153/discussion-between-sjoerd-smit-and-user64494).

Comment: I wonder the .upvoters. It is a bad practice to approve a wrong  answer.

Comment: Sjoerd Smit : Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such manner.